# Do I have to Keep my questions Family Show Friendly?

Tags: discussion

Can I ask Movie and TV questions about things that were let's say Adult entertainment. OK I will put it this way as a scale:

1. lower end of offensive content: movie Blue Lagoon
2. In the middle the Australian 90'S tv Show Chances. Quite a bit of nudity. Definitely only for adults. But not yet absolute pron.
3. Then there's TV and movies that were pron such as a station in Australia called SBS [special broadcasting services] that in the 90's showed stuff was full on pron including some banned movies like that one about the centipede.

I am happy to not ask about any of this if it's not appropriate. I am also not going to put in pictures or links; my questions would be totally text.